Any Sylow pro-$p$ subgroup of a topologically finitely generated profinite group is also topologically finitely generated?
It's proved in Oltikar and Ribes - On prosupersolvable groups that any Sylow pro-$p$ subgroup of a topologically finitely generated prosupersolvable group is also topologically finitely generated. It leads to the following natural question:

Is it true that any Sylow pro-$p$ subgroup of a topologically finitely
generated profinite group is also topologically finitely generated for any prime $p$?

If the answer is negative, then what about the following weaker statement:

Let $G$ be a topologically finitely generated profinite group. Is it true that there exists a prime $p$ such that the Sylow pro-$p$ subgroup of $G$ is topologically finitely generated?


No.
First for groups $A,B$ with $B$ finite and $A$ abelian, define $A\wr_0 B$ as $A^B_0\rtimes B$, with $A^B_0$ the subset of $A^B$ of $B$-tuples of sum zero.
Fix a prime $q$ and consider the product $\prod_{p:p\neq q}C_q\wr_0 C_p$. It's f.g. but its unique $q$-Sylow is not.
The argument that is it f.g. relies on the fact that $C_q\wr_0 C_p$ is generated by two elements of order $p$, so the whole product is generated by a pair.
For the second question, let $n\mapsto p_n$ and $n\mapsto q_n$ be sequences of primes, with $p_n\neq q_n$, $n\mapsto p_n$ injective, and $q\mapsto q_n$ with all infinite fibers. Then the product $\prod_n C_{q_n}\wr_0 C_{p_n}$ might do the job (its $p$-Sylow is infinitely generated for every $p$ but I haven't checked properly whether it's f.g.).
(Edit: I initially proposed the plain wreath product instead. But $C_q\wr C_p$ surjects onto $C_q$, so the product $\prod_{p: p\neq q}C_q\wr C_p$ is not f.g. as is surjects onto $C_q^J$ where $J$ is the set of primes $\neq q$.)
